# Aggregating data in two different ways within a single record

Tags: sql, ms-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need help for my SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352750/need-help-for-my-sql-query)

Well I may have posted this earlier also, but my requirements changed a bit, so please help me on this one.

My database structure:

**ATT** (`Activity` table)

- Act_ID(PK)
- Assigned_To_ID (FK, refer to `Emp_ID`)
- Project_ID (FK, refer to `Project_ID`)
- Product_ID (FK, refer to `Product_ID`)
- Status (can be `New, OnHold, Cancel, Closed`)

**Product_Table**

- Product_ID (PK)
- Product_Name

**Project_Table**

- Project_ID (PK)
- Project_Name

**Employee_Table**

- Emp_ID (PK)
- F_Name.

**Emp_Product_Project_Mapping**

(This table basically maps which employee is assigned to which product and which project. Duplicates entry are allowed in all the 3 columns, to map that 1 employee can be assigned to multiple project or products)

- Emp_IDFK(FK refer to Emp_ID PK)
- Product_IDFK(FK refer to Product_ID PK)
- Project_IDFK(FK refer to Project_ID PK)

**Constraints**

- In 1 Project --> Multiple employees can work
- 1 Employee -- > Can be assigned multiple activities (`Act_ID`)
- At any given point of time `Status` can be any of those given values.
- At any given point an activity can be assigned to 1 product and 1 project.

Now in my SQL query what I want to do is a load check ::

An activity (represented by `Act_ID`) is assigned to an employee is represented by `Assigned_To_ID`, for Project (`Project_ID` in `ATT_Table`) for product(`Product_ID` in `ATT_table`) and a particular status. I need to output 5 values from my SQL query:

1. Name of Employee
2. Name of Product
3. Number of total activities assigned for that Product(in 2) where Status is either New or InProcess.(Here, i am taking count of all the activities that are related to Product (in 2).No matter to whom it is assigned. Its not related to Employee (in 1). That i want in my 4rth part).
4. Now,i want the count of activities that Employee (in 1) is assigned to(out of total count in i have got from (3)). Hope i am making myself clear. In 3rd it was Total activities assigned to product(in 2). In 4rth its activities out of my result of 3rd, assigned to an employee in 1st.
5. Load. That will be = (Result in 3)/(result in 4) * 100 ((Result in 3) is a larger value than (result in 4), which is obvious.)

Now There may be a condition That an employee let's say E1 is working on product P1,P2. So my table output will be look like this::

```
1    2     3    4     5
E1   P1    
E1   P2
```

So here 3, 4, 5 will be having values corresponding to activities for that Product(P1 or P2)

Please help me on this one. Using MSaccess database. 
Thanks..

Comment: just tell me where to send the invoice

Comment: Well, this is somewhat related to my previous post.. and this is kind of an edited ques. Please refer to link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352750/need-help-for-my-sql-query/10353148#comment13370080_10353148 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to "group" your data in two independent ways, you can't do it with a single `GROUP BY` clause.  You must instead count the total number of activities for each product with a subquery; here I'm also using a subquery to count each employee's activities on those products, since I think it's easier to understand than mixing one `GROUP BY` subquery with a `GROUP BY` in the parent:

```
SELECT
  Employee_Table.F_Name,
  Product_Table.Product_Name,
  AllActivities.Count,
  EmployeeActivities.Count,
  EmployeeActivities.Count / AllActivities.Count AS Load
FROM
  Employee_Table, Product_Table
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Product_ID, COUNT(*) AS Count
    FROM ATT
    GROUP BY Product_ID
  ) AS AllActivities ON
    AllActivities.Product_ID = Product_Table.Product_ID
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Assigned_To_ID, Product_ID, COUNT(*) AS Count
    FROM ATT
    GROUP BY Assigned_To_ID, Product_ID
  ) AS EmployeeActivities ON
        EmployeeActivities.Assigned_To_ID = Employee_Table.Emp_ID
    AND EmployeeActivities.Product_ID     = Product_Table.Product_ID
```

Comment: eggyal.. Thanks for your reply. I gt ur point. But its giving me an error in FROM clause. and it takes me to JOIN part after Employee_Table . I am using MSACCESS as my database.

Comment: @user1230183: I'm not all that familiar with Access - your question was tagged with [tag:mysql] (a completely different database system), which is how I ended up here.  However, I think the revised answer might work for you now?

Comment: Thanks.. i appreciate your effort. And my mistake, i tagged it in Mysql. but its still gives me an error in From clause. Goes to Inner join Next to the line INNER JOIN Product_Table. thanks again

Comment: Syntax error missing operator in query expression. It lies in this particular part :: (
    AllActivities.Product_ID = Product_Table.Product_ID
  )
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Assigned_To_ID, Product_ID, COUNT(*) AS Count
    FROM ATT
    GROUP BY Assigned_To_ID, Product_ID
  ) AS EmployeeActivities ON (
        EmployeeActivities.Assi

Comment: @user1230183: One day I'll have to read Microsoft's documentation.  How is it now?

Comment: I am not an active user of MS Access, yet from what little I know about it, you need to enclose your joins in brackets when you have multiple joins, basically like this: `... FROM ((table1 JOIN table2 ON ...) INNER JOIN table3 ON ...) INNER JOIN table4 ON ...`. (I hope someone will correct me in case I've mixed up something.)